# Validate antd form input in onChange with the value return by back-end API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, antd

In my project I have antd form which used to add school details. In that form, I have ID field which need to be validated with back-end in onChange when input length = 5, whether that given ID is exists or not.

**antd version 4.18.2**

Field validations are handled via `rules` attribute in `Form.item`.

I use `validator` function to handle this custom validation.

State values

```
  const [idStatus, setIdStatus] = useState(false); // this value is get by API call.
  const [validateStatus, setValidateStatus] = useState("");
```

Form ID field

```
<Form form={form} name="form" onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Row className="applicationFormContent">
      <Col span={8}>
        <Form.Item
          name="schoolId"
          label="School Id"
          validateStatus={validateStatus}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: "Please Provide School ID!"
            },
            {
              len: 5,
              message: "School ID must have 5 digits"
            },
            {
              validator: validateId // validator is a function used for custom validation.
            }
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            type={"number"}
            maxLength={5}
            placeholder="Id - 00000 format"
            onChange={(e) => checkSchoolId(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  </Form>
```

Function triggered in onChange

```
const checkSchoolId = async (value) => {
try {
  if (value.length === 5) {
    let response = await checkId(value);
    console.log("-----", response.response?.data?.idExists);
    setIdStatus(response.response?.data?.idExists);
  } else {
    setValidateStatus("error");
  }
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
};
```

Validator function used in rules

```
const validateId = (rule, value) => {
if (idStatus) {
  // value return from API call.
  setValidateStatus("error");
  return Promise.reject("Census Id Already Exist");
} else {
  setValidateStatus("success");
  return Promise.resolve();
}
};
```

**Problem:**

when the input length = 5, I get the value from backend and it updates the state. But validator function is not triggered with that update. Which means Form input is not being re-rendered when update the state variable.
i logged the values and updated values are shown as it is.

But when I type one more number (input-lenght=6), show both validations and then delete one character (now input-length=5), it shows the validation get from back-end value.

how to solve this?

[example code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-form-validator-devman-gn9c24?file=/src/App.js:791-1067)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method named `form.validateFields(['array of input names need to validate'])` provided by `antd Form` for field validations.

With that I was able to re-execute the validation of the `schoolId` input when response come for `idStatus` inside a `useEffect` as below.

```
useEffect(() => {
// manually validate the field since input is not validated by form once state update.
form.validateFields(['schoolId']);
}, [idStatus]);
```

With the above way, we can manually trigger validation for particular `Form.Item` in antd Form wherever we want.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to say and please don't leave unlike if it's not true. but when you pass validator method in your rules like below:

```
 validator: validateId
```

acutely you reference your validator into your method and the data and state that use in this method get initial state from first and never update. for solving this instead of passing reference to validator pass it as arrow-function and also pass your idStatus stat as arguments of method.
something like bellow

```
 validator: (rule, value) => validateId(rule, value, idStatus)
```

with this approach you force your application to run this method each time want check validator.

Comment: I changed the validator function as you shown, but validation is not get triggered with that updated value. I console.log the idStatus passed via validator but it shows the prev value.

Comment: so try to set all the rules inside the useState and pass rules as state into the rules. and let me know if this work to update the answer for other guys

Comment: add all the rules is not feasible due to this is not the only field in the form. Form consists with 10+ input fields with different rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
  useEffect(() => {

  form.validateFields(['schoolId']);

  }, [form.getFieldValue("schoolId")]);
```